# Can you tell me how is this called and how can I make this?

Tags: discussion

I’ve recently seen people using this: [image: picture] when I saw this, really frustrated me because I don’t know how is made this yellow thing on the sentences nor to know how is called, because I want to know because I want to improve my question just like others, and I want to do this in my iPhone, is it possible on iPhone to be done this? Or in laptop? And if I want to grow a word with any color I want, how can I do that in iPhone, if it possible? Sorry if this question is introduced into a wrong site, and tell me if it wrong here, where to ask this?

Comment: Check the editing help on [blockquotes](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes).

Comment: @III-AK-III Sorry, I want to know on IPhone not on laptop. When I entered this{} it shows me “enter code here”, so what code I need to make blockquote?

Comment: @III-AK-III Can you give me a very clear answer, please? It would be nice like that.

Comment: Just add > in front of the first line of text you want to appear as a blockquote.

Comment: @III-AK-III I hope it works on IPhone

Comment: @III-AK-III I tried but it does not happen anything.

Comment: Yes, finally it happened

Comment: Thanx very much

Comment: @III-AK-III Oh, and how can I put the blue color on a word or a sentence? Or red color for example, how can I put it? Because, every time I’m trying to put blue color a word or sentence, it does not work. How I’m suppose to do? Does this also works on iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

Ordinarily, the markdown can be seen by clicking "edit".  In [III-AK-III's answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/44381/17163), it is:

```
In As-Silsila As-Sahiha, Maktabat al-Ma'arif: 1994, Vol. 1, pp. 787-789, hadith 426, Nasir al-Din al-Albani wrote:

> الْمُؤْمِنُ يَأْلَفُ وَيُؤْلَفُ وَلَا خَيْرَ فِيمَنْ لَا يَأْلَفُ وَلَا يُؤْلَفُ وَخَيْرُ النَّاسِ أَنْفَعُهُمْ لِلنَّاسِ
>
> <sub>_— NOTE: My own translation, so treat with care:_</sub>
>
> The believer befriends and is befriended. There is no good in those who do not befriend or be befriended. The best people are those who benefit other people most.
>
> <sub>— [As-Silsila As-Sahiha](https://www.archive.org/stream/waq47652/sahiha01#page/n786/mode/1up)</sub>
```

The [markdown](https://islam.stackexchange.com/editing-help) is the same on the iPhone and on a computer.  It's harder to read, input, and copy/paste on the iPhone, though.

To achieve blockquotes, we start a sentence with `>`.  For example

```
> Hello world
```

gives

> Hello world

---

The blue colors are from links.  Font colors in general are not implemented (see [meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115455)).